# How to use CodeSmithyUMLWebWidget to create a Class Diagram

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dynamic site where I can generate a Class Diagram (for a school project)

To do this I want to use de libraries provided by CodeSmithyUMLWebWidget.
( https://github.com/CodeSmithyIDE/UMLWebWidget )

The examples provided are really basic, but I managed to generate a classdiagram. So far so good :)

The problem I am having is in how to define the connectionpoints. The provides js library defines connections points as for example "left-center"

I don't know a lot about Javascript so I need some help from you guys.

Can somebody look into the script and give me an example on how to define the connectionpoints?

All the help is appreciated

The JS library has the following class:

...
class ConnectionPointPosition {

```
constructor(type) {
    switch (type) {
        case "top-center":
            this.type = topCenter
            break

        case "top-right":
            this.type = topRight
            break
```

...

Comment: I mailed the creator of the script several times over the last week but with no answer (yet) so I realy need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, you need to define it in the layout of your elements as shown below:

```
      var layout = {
    "elements": {
      "startElement": { position: { "x": 1, "y": 65 } },
      "endElement": { position: { "x": 100, "y": 5 } },
      "startElement-endElement-inheritance": { "end": "left-center" }
      }
    }
```